# Subtraction of very large numbers with modulus

Tags: math

I need to subtract two very large integers along with modulus of 1000000007

x and y are integers 1 <= x,y <= 1000

```
long long s[x+1];
long long c[x+1];

for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
  c[i] = power(y,i)%mod;

s[1]=1;
for(int i=2;i<=x;i++){
    sum=0;
    for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
        sum = (sum + (s[j]*c[i-j]%mod))%mod;
    }
    s[i] = (c[i] - sum)%mod; // <----------- s[i] is -ve 
}
```

The issue is when `c[i]%mod` is less than `Sum%mod`

Eg: When c[i] is greater than Sum. 
But `c[i]%mod` is less than `Sum%mod`
437001927 - 952742480

Comment: Care to explain what your code is supposed to do? What is `x`? What does `calctotal` do? What are `s` and `c`? And what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an `if` statement.

```
if(s[i]<0)
  s[i] += mod
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
s[i] = (c[i] - sum + mod) % mod;
```

in this case. `sum` is computed modulo `mod`, so it can't be greater than `mod`.